# Bitnami redmine change port on Windows

Tags: apache, redmine, bitnami

I have an Bitnami Redmine installation on my windows. I access my redmine at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/redmine. this works well.
Now I want to change the port so that I can access http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8060/redmine

But when I change my httpd.conf file from my Apache I can't find the redmine homepage.

Did I miss something or does somebody has a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Are you running under bitnami? if so, there's an extra step of updating this file:
apache2\conf\bitnami\bitnami.conf

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you (see item 8) http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_a_sub-URI_on_Windows_with_Apache

...
8. Assuming that we will be hosting Redmine under `http://localhost/redmine`
Edit C:\webserver\Redmine\config\environment.rb file to configure Redmine to work as a sub-URI (Apache configuration is also required and is listed later on in this document).
add the following line at the bottom of the file:

```
Redmine::Utils::relative_url_root = "/redmine"
```